# Lagrangian for FRW metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, geodesics

For the metric

$$ds^2=-dt^2+a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2),$$

$$L= \sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{dt}\frac{dx^\beta}{dt}}$$

How does this become

$$L= \sqrt{1-a^2 (\frac{dx}{dt})^2}~? $$

I guess we get 1 because $g_{tt}=-1$, but what about the other terms?

Comment: Have you tried simply carrying out the sum?

Comment: Are you sure that in your last expression you have only de time derivative of the $x$ coordinate and not the spacial velocity? Or that you are not restringed to 1-dim problem?

Comment: No, it is of 4d spacetime, but the motion is restricted to x direction along a timelike geodesic where t is a non affine parameter..

Comment: are you sure, that's not supposed to be $\left(\frac{d{\vec x}}{dt}\right)^{2}$?